# Simulating polymers using cellular automata?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, monte-carlo, polymers

I am a physics student, and I am working on my final year project, I am planning to simulate polymers using cellular automata. I am really struggling with this project, if someone can give me any indications, I am going to be glad.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's an interesting topic but, as is, I think your question is too broad. It would help other users if you could narrow the question down to a more specific problem. Are you having trouble finding references on this topic? Having difficulty understanding the underlying math? Struggling to write/find code that can perform these simulations?  Any of these individually would make for a good question, along with context from you about why you understand or have attempted so far.

Comment: To add to the comments above, there are a great number of possible properties. What kind of polymer(s) and/or properties are you trying to simulate?

Comment: Did you know [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0167-8191(00)00081-8) and [this](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812819420_0007) references?

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, the question should be more detailed.

However, for starters and in general, I would start by giving a cursory read to any wide piece of work that contains this problem, in order to get some perspective. For example in the PhD thesis [Cellular automata methods in mathematical physics](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/33501/31019424-MIT.pdf), where chapter 5 is dedicated to **Modeling Polymers with Cellular Automata** but there is some background that should help you get situated, such as Cellular Automata as models of nature or the question of reversibility vs dissipation. It's 25 years old but the general principles will not have changed.

Once you have a good grasp on the general problem you want to solve, the system you are going to study and why the technique you want to apply can be useful, you can dig into the bibliography with some more focus, and also to select more recent works.